# Retrieve a URL of a frame

Tags: javascript

If I get a link

`<a href="/Users/ChangePassword.aspx" target="mainFrame">` in fraTopMenu, what 
(1) javascript can I add to get the current **mainFrame's URL** upon clicking the link and 
(2) append the URL to the querystrings?

```
<frameset rows="60,*" cols="*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
      <frame src="/Common/Manager/TopMenu.aspx"  name="fraTopMenu" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" id="fraTopMenu" title="" />
      <frameset rows="*" cols="185,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="no" border="0">
        <frame src="..." name="leftFrame" id="leftFrame" title="" />
        <frame src="..." name="mainFrame" id="mainFrame" title="" />
      </frameset>
    </frameset>
```

Thank you.

Comment: `frameset` and `frame` is deprecated in HTML5 and you are adviced to replace whese with `iframe` based markup.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use frames.
2. Don't use frames.
3. `document.getElementById('mainFrame').location`

Answer (score 1):

You can access the frames location by using

```
alert(window.frames["mainFrame"].contentWindow.location.href);
```

But you should avoid `frameset` and `frame` as these are deprecated in XHTML and in HTML5.

Comment: Hi, how do I append it to the querystring of the href when clicking the <a> mentioned above.